# my js is working fine on chrome and safari

Tags: jquery, ajax

My jquery is working fine on chrome and safari but not in IE and Mozilla. What could be the reason.I am following the [This](http://designshack.co.uk/tutorialexamples/buzzinglogin/index.html) Example. IE is showing a prompt for save, open file.

Comment: That example works just fine in Firefox, so the problem is more likely to be in *your* code. If you could post that here, that would help a lot.

Comment: You have no hope of getting an informative answer if you don't tell anyone which code isn't working, what it's supposed to do, and what the specific problem you're having with it is. If you're getting any error messages (check the browser's javascript error console) they would be very useful.

Comment: post some code and error messages or put it on jsfiddle.net if You really want to get help.

Comment: Seeing your edit you may even have a problem with serving files

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Assuming what you wan't is that your form should shake when login fails.

Look in the vibrate.js file, it uses WebkitTransform (Safari and Chrome is both based on Webkit):

```
WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' +rotate +'deg)
```

There better ways to do rotation in all browser that supports CSS3, take a look at this for example:
http://www.robertnyman.com/css3/css-transitions/css-transitions-mac-os-x-stacks.html

So, this line:

```
t.css({position: 'relative', left: leftPos +'px', top: topPos +'px', WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' +rotate +'deg)'});
```

Should instead look something like this:

```
var r ='rotate(' +rotate +'deg)';
t.css({position: 'relative', left: leftPos +'px', top: topPos +'px',
    "-moz-transform": r, "-webkit-transform": r, "-o-transform": r, "transform": r});
```